# Symfony API Request Unexpected "G"

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, google-books

I'm really thrown off by this error I get when posting to Google Books API. The last response in this function is triggered when I post `1781100489` to a form. This form then runs `resultAction` function. Instead of returning what I want it to, I get a JSON.parse error with an unexpected token in line 1 column 1.

When tested with Postman, it gives me this peculiar message in its response `Unexpected 'G'`. What could this mean? I have been dumping the variable as you can see, it's commented, but can't understand why this is occuring.

Any clues?

```
public function findAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->add('Title', TextType::class)
        ->add('Search', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('Title')->getData());
        $response = json_decode($json, true);

        if(array_key_exists('items', $response)){
            return $this->render('BlogsiteBooksBundle:Pages:results.html.twig', [
                'items' => $response['items']
            ]);
        } else {
            return new Response('Google did not have any items', 400);
        }
    }

    //var_dump($request);

    return new Response('Google Book Not Found', 404);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `$form->get('Title')->getData()` used. using `1781100489` return a valid json with only one book `Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone`

Comment: @rafrsr Should be `1781100489`. I enter it into a form text box, of type `text` with name and id `Title`, and GET with action `/result`. `$form` is null when var dumped, any reason?

Comment: I figured it out. The G comes from first char in the raw data dump, this would be last response in the code. If I `var_dump` it gives `<` because there is HTML code wrapped around the variable I dumped. The variable I dumped is `$form` which is null. Any ideas?

Comment: Can share your twig? in order to view and test all in context

Comment: The twig is simple, just this:
`<form action="/find" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is not related to the form, build the form using Symfony form component in the controller, and manually in the twig, then parameters names does not match. The `$form->handleRequest($request);` can't find the title, because expect a parameter called `form[Title]` and you are passing only `Title`.

Solutions:

1 - Submit manually all given parameters in the query

Change:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

For this:

```
$form->submit($request->query->all());
```

2 - Change the name of the input to match with symfony expected name and the method used should be POST:

```
<form action="app_dev.php/find" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="form[Title]" id="Title" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

3 - Render your form using twig form to avoid this problems

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route(name="find", path="/find")
     */
    public function findAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
                     ->add('Title', TextType::class)
                     ->add('Search', SubmitType::class)
                     ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('Title')->getData());
            $response = json_decode($json, true);
            if (array_key_exists('items', $response)) {
                return $this->render(
                    'BlogsiteBooksBundle:Pages:results.html.twig',
                    [
                        'items' => $response['items'],
                    ]
                );
            } else {
                $form->addError(new FormError('Google did not have any items'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('find.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
```

View <kbd>find.html.twig</kbd>:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Note: each point is a possible solution, use only one of them, the third is the recommended for simple Symfony forms.

Comment: How would you suggest I build it? Generate it using doctrine or just type it manually?

Comment: review the answer updated with the third solution and recommended for simple Symfony forms. Use the same controller to build and render the form, and to hande the request after submit.

Comment: Ok so Method 1 works well, but this is rather strange. I still get the JSON.parse error, but I can see all the data in html form with headers, tables etc in raw data.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but all the above cases are to use html forms and html respones, you are expecting a json like a API response?

Comment: I'd like it to get the data via API through JSON request and generate HTML so I am not sure why I'm getting JSON.parse error.

Comment: In the browser, and using Postman. When I leave JSON view and enter raw data view, I get the entire HTML showing.

Comment: Postman expect a json and your controller return a full html response ready to use in a browser, if its possible share more details of the error and your approach, and screenshot of the error.

Comment: I was testing it in Mozilla which shows JSON first. However, in Chrome, it's preformatted. How can I stop it being from preformatted so instead of displaying raw data it displays the actual result with the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same error in POSTMAN. I searched for answers but nothing was satisfying my problem.
I find by self that their is a statement "exit();" in my PHP file. I removed it & my problem was solved. I hope my solution help someone.